# Where should I save standalone non-ruby scripts in my Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

This is a simple question, but I haven't been able to find an exact answer to it anywhere.

I have a standalone Python script which I am using in my Rails app. What is the appropriate folder I should save it in according to convention, so that I can push it to production (currently running it from my computer's desktop)? I think the answer is `lib/assets` but I want to make sure.

Comment: If it will run standalone just put it in bin/. Or just create a folder called tools or whatever you like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is an exact answer for this question.

If it is a ruby script, it is usually placed in `lib` or `bin`.

From the rails folder descriptions in [Getting Started with Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) guide:

> bin/    Contains the rails script that starts your app and can contain
>   other scripts you use to setup, deploy or run your application.
>
> lib/    Extended modules for your application.

You could put it in `lib/assets` folder as it reflects your understanding that it is an external asset used in the system.